# How can I get latest id column with select query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, identity-column

I'm beginner in SQL Server and created a simple table which has an `id bigint identity(1,1)` column. In my stored procedure I use this query on that table:

```
select *
from TABLEA
where id > @id
```

I want to return the latest of id column value with stored procodure with this line:

```
SET  @ResultValue = latest id column
```

How can I write that? Thanks.

Comment: And you can simply use "SELECT MAX(id) FROM TABLEA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last identity value generated, regardless of when or where it was generated, you can use [`IDENT_CURRENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx):

```
SELECT @id=IDENT_CURRENT('TABLEA')
```

If you want the last identity created inside your stored procedure scope, use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx), but this will return the last identity in scope **in any** table, so if you generated an identity in table A, then table B, you can't get table A's identity this way:

```
SELECT @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY('TABLEA')
```

Comment: thanks for answer,it's work,please wait 2 minute for accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum value of the column like this:

```
SET @ResultValue = IDENT_CURRENT('TABLEA')
```

Or if you just want the most recent values you have just inserted in this query batch, you can use [`@@IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187342.aspx) and/or [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190315.aspx):

```
SET @ResultValue = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```